# White box over top navigation while css animations or toggle navigation in progress

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using AdminLTE free template for my site, did some changes in .js and a lot of new css, so I cant post some block of code here to see the problem, but, maybe someone would have a idea out of top of their heads. Here is also a link to my website to see it...try toggle, animations I had is turned off because of this problem...
[This is my website](https://www.betskiller.com/dashboard)

[White box on top while navigation toggle or css animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpDeA.png)

[image: How it usually looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time this flickering comes from `overflow: hidden`.
Modify your wrapper, but I don't know why it has it. Could be a hack or a trick to clear any floats or anything.

Just disable it and your wrapper should look like:

```
.wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
   position: static;
   /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

If you do that your animation won't flicker.
Why it happens? Badly structured HTML and CSS positioning (sorry for being mean).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will do that... I guess that is a risk of free templates, plus I am not so experienced to notice and fix...